# It is possible Using Sitefinity to create a Custom CMS for clients?

Tags: sitefinity

I want to make an Application which itself will be a CMS, and I will require it to have my own UI, Can I build something like that using sitefinity, The app will allow some user to create/edit projects and assign to other users.
 some other users can then edit content of the projects, and some other who can only view content ?

All content in a project will be arranged in some hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about your project, I can say it is possible.

Sitefinity has a module called the Module Builder.  This will allow you to create content types that can be linked in a hierarchy or linked as two separate entities.

Each content type can also have permissions set to only allow specific users view, create, update, delete, or even assign an owner.  Each DynamicContent object has a IsGranted() method that you can check permissions before displaying or modifying the content.  Each content item also has an owner so you could use that to assign content items to people as you are suggesting.

As part of the module builder, Sitefinity will generate an administrative UI to modify content but there isn't a lot of flexibility to change this UI.  You can create your own UI completely separate of Sitefinity and just call the Sitefinity API's.  Sitefinity provides access through C# APIs or HTTPS REST endpoints.

Hope this helps and good luck on your project.

Craig